# resize/scale text dynamically in andengine

Tags: android, text, andengine

I created a simple game where move the objects from one place to another and each moves increment count of moves in score table. After all objects are moved correct I want set opacity to screen and slowly resizing score from initial size(e.g. 15px) to whole screen(e.g. 50px). I load font like this:

```
    FontFactory.setAssetBasePath("font/");
    final ITexture mainFontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    font = FontFactory.createStrokeFromAsset(activity.getFontManager(), mainFontTexture, activity.getAssets(), "font.ttf", 15, true, Color.WHITE, 2, Color.BLACK);
    font.load();
```

In createScene() method I create HUD with text and I initial text:

```
Int mMoves = 0;
HUD gameHUD = new HUD();
Text mText = new Text(25, 25, font, "Moves: " + "123456789", getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

And each moves set text with actual moves count:

```
mText.setText("Moves: " +  mMoves++);
```

And when level was complete I don't know how can I resize this text. I mean something like scale with transition in CSS3..
Thanks for all comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the size of the text by using the setscale function.

If you just want to set the  size use the following :
Example : `mText.setScale(1.5f);`

You can also use Entity modifiers to create an animation:

```
ScaleModifier scale = new ScaleModifier(1f, 1f, 1.1f);
LoopEntityModifier loop = new LoopEntityModifier(scale);
mText.registerEntityModifier(loop);
```

This will give a animation effect re-sizing the text in a loop.

Comment: Thank a lot Renier

ScaleModifier scale = new ScaleModifier(2.5f, 1f, 3f);
mText.registerEntityModifier(scale);

 is what I want :)